# Creating html elements using jQuery and for loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create html elements using jQuery creating new elements with an attribute object like so:

```
var i, j, columns=3, arr=[], numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
arr.push($('<div></div>', {
    append: function() {
        var elem ='';
        for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j += columns) {
            elem += $('<div></div>', {
                 append: function() {
                    return numbers[j + i];
                   }
                 });
        }
        return elem;
    }
 }));
}
```

How can I achieve this output:

```
<div>
  <div>1</div><div>4</div><div>7</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>2</div><div>5</div><div>8</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>3</div><div>6</div><div>9</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: jQuery objects aren't strings, you can't concatenate them like that.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, typo on my part :) Do you have alternative solution?

Comment: What is desired output here? How many rows you want? In this case, you can get 6 rows, actually? 1,4,7||2,5,8||3,6,9||4,7,10||5,8,11||6,9,12? Do you want to limit result to 3 rows, for some reason, or go to the end of array?

Comment: @sinisake The number of rows is defined by columns var.

Comment: Ah, so... ok, maybe something like this, i've defined rows and cols, too: https://jsfiddle.net/mc2nyukx/ problem is when rows var is set to high, so you can get out of array limit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first group the array items into multidimensional array like below.

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Then you can traverse through this multidimensional array and generating the `HTML`. For generation the HTML, trick is to create an map each group with `HTML String` array and then use `join` to combine all the items.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var result = []
numbers.forEach(function(element, index) {
  var group = index % 3;
  var temp = result[group];
  if (!Array.isArray(temp)) {
    temp = [];
  }
  temp.push(element);
  result[group] = temp;
});

var divs = result.map(function(group) {
  var groupHTML = ['<div>'];
  groupHTML = groupHTML.concat(group.map(function(item) {
    return '<div>' + item + '</div>'
  }))
  groupHTML.push('</div>');
  return groupHTML.join('');
});

console.log(divs.join(''))
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your solution (at least comment the code). I'm sure OP appreciates your effort, but code-only answers get flagged as low quality - people are here to **learn** how to solve issues, not only to have someone solve it for them.

Comment: Thanks @Vipin Kumar, your solution output each element of numbers array, the output should be every 3th/nth element of numbers array <div>
  <div>1</div><div>4</div><div>7</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>2</div><div>5</div><div>8</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>3</div><div>6</div><div>9</div>
</div>

Comment: I didn't understood what you are trying to say in above comment. Please explain.

Comment: Please see updated answer, it is generating the same string like you asked `<div><div>1</div><div>4</div><div>7</div></div><div><div>2</div><div>5</div><div>8</div></div><div><div>3</div><div>6</div><div>9</div></div>`

Comment: thanks @VipinKumar, was trying to avoid using multidimensional/nested array for this to work, but it works thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, without using array of arrays:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]; // can be anything,strings too...html portions...
cols=3;
rows=3; // or limit rows by Math.ceil(numbers.length/cols)
every=3; // every Nth element
html_string='';
for(j=0;j<rows;j++) {

html_string+='<div>\n';

for(i=0;i<cols;i++) {
k=(i*every)+j;

if(numbers[k]) { // check if we are out of array
html_string+='<div>';
html_string+=numbers[k];
html_string+='</div>';
}

}
html_string+='\n</div>\n';

}

console.log(html_string);
```

Demo:

```js
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
cols=3;
rows=3; // or limit rows by Math.ceil(numbers.length/cols)
every=3; // every Nth element
html_string='';
for(j=0;j<rows;j++) {

html_string+='<div>\n';

for(i=0;i<cols;i++) {
k=(i*every)+j;

if(numbers[k]) { // check if we are out of array
html_string+='<div>';
html_string+=numbers[k];
html_string+='</div>';
}

}
html_string+='\n</div>\n';

}

console.log(html_string);
```

And, then just append it somewhere on page.